# Black-Screen with the FlatButton in the AppBar

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My App contains basically 2 parts -> Appbar (with 1 Button) and BottomNavigationBar (with some buttons that works properly). The problem came when I pressed the Appbar button (goes to a black screen instead of show the "manual_page.dart")

this is the content of the 2 files (the home_page.dart and manual_page.dart):

**home_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:opening_a_pdf/manual_page.dart';
import 'package:opening_a_pdf/first_page.dart';
import 'package:opening_a_pdf/second_page.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _selectedPage = 0;
  List<Widget> pageList = List<Widget>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    pageList.add(FirstPage());
    pageList.add(SecondPage());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
      appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      title: const Text('Aplicación en Desarrollo'),
            actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text(
              'MANUAL',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: (){ 
                Navigator.push(
                context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Voice()),
              );
            }
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedPage,
        children: pageList,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.compare_arrows),
            title: Text('Conectividad'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.blur_on),
            title: Text('Captura Datos'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.graphic_eq),
            title: Text('Voz'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            title: Text('Comandos'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Ajustes'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPage = index;
    });
  }
}
```

**manual_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class Voice extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sección de Órdenes por Voz"),
      ),
     body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Center(
              child: MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In bottomNavigationBar you use FirstPage() and Second Page, but in Appbar you use Voice(). Could you give more information about that?

Comment: Yes, both of them are using for show the content in the main screen without change the screen (only changes the content in the middle), but that works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initial the height of container in the second screen before Stack

Comment: How can I do that? (I don´t understand properly).

Comment: Container ( height : 300 , width: 300, child : Stack( .. )))

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code and found no problem with it:

[image]

But you can put empty `Container()` as the `child` of `MaterialButton()`.

Corrected code:

```
MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Colors.red,
            child:Container(),
          ),
```

Comment: The problem persist, it doesn´t appear the red element. I tried copying a simple example with a button on the center (for test only the transition between screens), and happens the same.. Black screen :s

Answer (score 0):

There are no errors in the code. Works correctly. Maybe the fault is in the main () or in the emulator.
Code in main:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]